How to incorporate file renaming with FileSystemWatcher?
I have a FileSystemWatcher script that monitors the XML-TO-TRANSFORM folder for XML and audio files. When a new file is created in that folder, the FileSystemWatcher detects it, grabs the XML, applies an XSLT transform, and then moves both the XML and audio file to the XML-FINAL folder.
However, I encounter an issue when a filename contains the [ or ] characters. The FileSystemWatcher detects the file but cannot continue processing. It just hangs and then resumes monitoring without handling the file.
I have tried various methods of renaming the file, but each time, after the file is renamed, the FileSystemWatcher does not grab it.
Is there any way to ensure that the FileSystemWatcher can grab the file, rename it if necessary, and then proceed with the transform?
Thanks,
$PathToMonitor = "C:\XML-TO-TRANSFORM\"
$PathToExport  = "C:\XML-FINAL\"
$PathToXSLT    = "C:\VMLtoAMU.xslt"

# Create the locked file function
function Test-LockedFile {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName', 'FilePath')]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path
    )
    $file = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($Path)
    try {
        $stream = $file.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
        if ($stream) { $stream.Close() }
        return $false
    }
    catch {
        return $true
    }
}

# Create the FileSystemWatcher path and filter
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.xml"

# Include subdirectories
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false

# Make sure the watcher emits events
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Define the code that should execute when a file change is detected
$Action = {
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $Name = $details.Name
    $Path = $details.FullPath
    $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    $text = "{0} was {1} at {2}" -f $Name, $ChangeType, $Timestamp
    # This will happen every change regardless of change type
    
    # Code executed based on specific file change type
    switch ($ChangeType) {
        'Changed' { 
            "NOTHING(FSW.Changed is broken from Microsoft and double triggers regularly)" 
        }
        'Created' {  
            Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - $text"
                
            # Test XML is finished writing
            while (Test-LockedFile $Path) {
                Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - XML file still writing to folder, can't move yet"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            }
            # Process XML after it is finished writing
            $Transform = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform 
            try {    
                $Transform.Load($PathToXSLT)
                $Transform.Transform($Path, $PathToExport + $Name)
                Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - $Name transformed and moved to $PathToExport"
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - $_" -ForegroundColor Red
            }

            # Check for audio file with the same name as the XML
            try {
                $wavcheck = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
                $wavext = ".wav"
                $audiofile = "$PathToMonitor$wavcheck$wavext"
                if (Test-Path "$audiofile") {
                    Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Audio file exists moving $wavcheck$wavext to $PathToExport"

                    # If file exists do another check for finished writing before moving audio file with XML file
                    while (Test-LockedFile $audiofile) {
                        Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Audio file still writing to folder, can't move yet"
                        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                    }
                    Move-Item -LiteralPath $audiofile -Destination $PathToExport -Force
                } else {
                    Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Audio file not found, re-checking once in 100 ms!"
                    Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - $PathToMonitor$wavcheck$wavext"
                    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
                    if (Test-Path "$audiofile") {
                        Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Audio file exists moving $wavcheck$wavext to $PathToExport"

                        # Another check for finished writing before moving audio file with XML file
                        while (Test-LockedFile $audiofile) {
                            Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Audio file still writing to folder, can't move yet"
                            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                        }
                        Move-Item -LiteralPath $audiofile -Destination $PathToExport -Force
                    } else {
                        Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Audio file still not found, assuming no audio" -ForegroundColor Red
                        Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - $PathToMonitor$wavcheck$wavext"
                    }
                }
                if (Test-Path "$Path") {
                    Remove-Item $Path
                }
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - $_" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
        'Deleted' { 
            # Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - "
            # Write-Host $text
        }
        'Renamed' { 
            "NOTHING" 
        }
        default { 
            Write-Host $_ 
        }
    }
}

# Add event handlers
$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Changed -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSChange
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Deleted -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSDelete
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Renamed -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSRename
}

Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Watching for changes to $PathToMonitor press CTRL+C to stop watching"

try {
    do {
        # Write datetime and a watcher reminder every 10 minutes
        Wait-Event -Timeout 600
        Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Watching for changes to $PathToMonitor press CTRL+C to stop watching"
    } while ($true)
}
finally {
    # This gets executed when user presses CTRL+C and is the proper way to halt the watcher process
    # Remove the event handlers
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSChange
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSDelete
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSRename
    # Remove background jobs
    $handlers | Remove-Job
    # Remove FileSystemWatcher
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    Write-Host "$((Get-Date).toString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")) - Dispose successful, no longer monitoring"
    Stop-Transcript
}


Make sure you pass the file path to the -LiteralPath parameter of any provider cmdlet - otherwise [...] will be interpreted as a wildcard, ie. Test-Path $_ -> Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ (repeat for all the Test-Path calls in your script, including Test-Path $audiofile -> Test-Path -LiteralPath $audiofile)

You are using quite different actions for different events: it's better to use different variables for each event.

Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen! I missed adding the parameter to those, but that did the trick!
